# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method) at A.method2

Tags: java, concurrency

```
public class A {

Object o = new Object();

public void method2(){
    synchronized (o) {
        notifyAll();
        System.out.println("hi!");
    }
}

public void method1(){
    synchronized (o) {
        someMethod();
    }
}

public void someMethod(){}

}
/---------------------------------------------------------

public class B extends A {

@Override
public void someMethod(){
    method2();
}
}
/----------------------------------------------------------

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    B b2 = new B();
    b2.method1();
}
}
```

старт программы вызывает

> *Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException    at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)    at A.method2(A.java:22)*

Это не согласуется с описанием *IllegalMonitorStateException* : поток захватывает тот же монитор! В чем причина исключения?

Comment: И еще: не используйте синхронизацию по не final полю. Это может привести к плохим последствиям.

Comment: @zzashpaupat к каким , можно поподробнее ?

Comment: насколько понимаю, лок может быть подменен в рантайме

Comment: Да, верно, лок может быть подменен. Смотрите пример:
https://ideone.com/zrJrYF

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте вызвать notifyAll у о, а не просто так, монитором обьекта, то o служит.
Подобные переменные который служат как лочка вообще лучше так и называть типа lock